# Rails: Selecting user comments for the last day

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have User model. I have Comment model. Here is their relation:

```
User.rb:
  has_many :replies, :through => :items, :source => :comments
```

I'm trying to print out all replies of the User for the past day. This way:

```
user.replies.find(:all, :conditions => [" created_at between ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day, Time.zone.now.end_of_day])
```

And here is the problem I get:

> ruby-1.9.2-p180 :038 > bob.replies.all(:conditions => [" created_at
>   between ? AND ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day,
>   Time.zone.now.end_of_day]) ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:
>   Mysql::Error: Column 'created_at' in where clause is ambiguous: SELECT
>   `comments`.* FROM `comments` INNER JOIN `items` ON `comments`.item_id
>   = `items`.id WHERE ((`items`.user_id = 16)) AND ( created_at between
>   '2011-08-25 00:00:00' AND '2011-08-25 23:59:59')

It seems that the problem is because of my User - Comment relation. But I don't really get what's going on and how to fix this. Help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to replace `created_at` with `comments.created_at` in your conditions. As you can see in the generated query, there are two tables joined: `comments` and `items`, they both have `created_at`. So your db is a little confused, which created at you are talking about.

Answer (score 0):

rubish is right; however you can also rewrite it as this:

```
User.replies.find(:all, :conditions => {:created_at => Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day..Time.zone.now.end_of_day})
```